# An example of a non-paracompact topological space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, paracompactness

The most famous example of a non-paracompact space is the long line. I saw in several places a reference to another example: the Cartesian product of uncountably many copies of an infinite discrete space is not paracompact. Although I have searched for a proof of this fact, I was unable to find one (or to prove it myself). Even the [Wikipedia article on paracompact spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space) mentions this fact without providing a reference.

Can someone explain why such a space is not-paracompact?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma woops I mixed together two results in my not so great memory ($\Bbb N^{\omega_1}$ is not normal and uncountable products of Hausdorff spaces with at least two points are never *hereditarily* normal)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti On that we can agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Bbb N^I$ for $I$ uncountable is not normal ($T_4$) as shown by Stone way back. So a fortiori not paracompact as a paracompact Hausdorff space is normal. A reference to this fact online can be found on [Dan Ma's nice blog](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/the-uncountable-product-of-the-countable-discrete-space-is-not-normal/). For the same reason the Sorgenfrey plane is not paracompact, despite being a square of a paracompact space etc.

The long line (and also the simpler $\omega_1$ in the order topology) is more "interesting" in that it *is* hereditarily normal and countably paracompact but not paracompact. So it's "sharper", as it were, closer to paracompact.